# Generate random number(from range) in a function, different value for each row

Tags: python, pandas

Hy
I trying to define a function that return a random number from a range, 
a different number for each row.

ive tried the following which returns the same number for each condition:

```
data['yom_7'] =[random.randint(1,14)  for k in data.index]

def to_cont(x):
    if x==1:
        return data['yom_7']
    elif x==2:
        return 22
    elif x==3:
        return 37
    elif x==4:
        return 57
    elif x==5:
        return 74.5
    elif x==6:
        return 90
    elif x==7:
        return 0

data['cont_var']=data['cat_var'].apply(to_cont)
```

Comment: This needs more context. What does your data dataframe look like? Maybe give a small example

Comment: i have a categorical variable which take 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
i want to make it a continuous variable which every category takes a random number from a range
every row a different value